# Selenium python loop over links

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Hi I want to loop over links I am retrieving from an access database and then get each link a number of times my code is as follows the problem is it gets to the second link and stops

```
count=0
for link in df['Links']:
    while count < 2:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
        driver.get("" + link)
        time.sleep(100)
        driver.close()
        count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it makes more sense to use a for-loop in this case:

```py
for link in df['Links']:
    for _ in range(2):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
        driver.get("" + link)
        time.sleep(100)
        driver.close()
```

`_` is a variable, much like `x` or `count` would act, but conventionally it's used when the variable is not used, such as this case.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `count=0` inside the for-loop. Otherwise, count stays at 2 and everything in the while-loop is skipped after the first iterations of the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code explicitly tells you to stop at the second iteration.

```
count=0 # sets up a counter
for link in df['Links']:
    while count < 2: # Don't count more than this number
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
        driver.get("" + link)
        time.sleep(100)
        driver.close()
        count = count + 1 # increase the counter for the next iteration
```

Below is a modification that puts the counter in the for loop.

```
for link in df['Links']:
    count=0 # sets up a fresh counter each iteration
    while count < 2: # Don't count more than this number
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
        driver.get("" + link)
        time.sleep(100)
        driver.close()
        count = count + 1 # increase the counter for the next iteration
```